# .Net 6 unit test project not able to load project references

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-6.0, .net-standard-2.0

- I am using Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise on Windows 10.
- I have a C# class library project targeting .Net standard 2.0 (let's call this `Project1`). This project has project reference to other C# class librabry where there are also targeting .Net standard 2.0.
- I created a .Net 6 unit test project (let's call this `UnitTestProject`) to test `Project1`.
- All of the projects are in the same solution.

The `UnitTestProject` has these package reference

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" />
<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" />
<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" />
```

```
Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 17.5.0
MSTest.TestAdapter 3.0.2
MSTest.TestFramework 3.0.2
```

The `UnitTestProject` is referencing `Project1` using project reference because there are in the same solution.

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="..\Project1\Project1.csproj">
  <Private>False</Private>
</ProjectReference>
```

This is the folder structure

```
C:\myapp\myapp.sln
C:\myapp\sources\Project1\Project1.cspoj
C:\myapp\sources\UnitTestProject\UnitTestProject.csproj
```

The build output

```
C:\myapp\sources\bin\Project1.dll
C:\myapp\sources\unittest\net6.0\UnitTestProject.dll
```

I am using a .runsettings file for the unit test project located in `C:\myapp\.runsettings`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <MSTest>
    <MapInconclusiveToFailed>True</MapInconclusiveToFailed>
    <CaptureTraceOutput>False</CaptureTraceOutput>
    <DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>False</DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>
    <DeploymentEnabled>True</DeploymentEnabled>
    <AssemblyResolution>
      <Directory path="..\..\" includeSubDirectories="true"/>
    </AssemblyResolution>
  </MSTest>
</RunSettings>
```

I can Clean and Rebuild all related projects without error, all succeeded.

But when I tried to execute any test method in `UnitTestProject`, the result shows

> Test run finished: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in < 1 ms

When I check the Test pane, with logging level set to Diagnostic. I see this message

> [Warning] [MSTest][Discovery][C:\myapp\sources\unittest\net6.0\UnitTestProject.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'C:\myapp\sources\unittest\net6.0\UnitTestProject.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
> Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Project1, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Also in the Test output pane, the runsetting is displayed with RunConfiguration.

```xml
<RunSettings>
  <MSTest>
    <MapInconclusiveToFailed>True</MapInconclusiveToFailed>
    <CaptureTraceOutput>False</CaptureTraceOutput>
    <DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>False</DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>
    <DeploymentEnabled>True</DeploymentEnabled>
    <AssemblyResolution>
      <Directory path="..\..\" includeSubDirectories="true" />
    </AssemblyResolution>
  </MSTest>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <ResultsDirectory>C:\myapp\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
    <SolutionDirectory>C:\myapp\</SolutionDirectory>
    <MaxCpuCount>0</MaxCpuCount>
    <EnvironmentVariables>
      <VSTEST_BACKGROUND_DISCOVERY>1</VSTEST_BACKGROUND_DISCOVERY>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
    <CollectSourceInformation>False</CollectSourceInformation>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

If I set the `Copy Local to Yes (<Private>True</Private>)` for the project reference, I am able to execute all test in the test project.

I have no idea what are the issues here, if the whole setup here is incorrect or something else, please help. Thanks.

I've tried building the `UnitTestProject` into unittest folder (without net6.0).

```
C:\myapp\sources\unittest\UnitTestProject.dll
```

And change `<Directory>` in the .runsettings from `..\..\` to `..\`

```xml
<AssemblyResolution>
  <Directory path="..\" includeSubDirectories="true"/>
</AssemblyResolution>
```

It is still not working.

I even tried target the `Project1` to .Net 6, not working as well.

---

Edit #1:

I enabled the logging level to Trace, and in the trace file

> AssemblyResolver.OnResolve: Project1: Resolving assembly.
> AssemblyResolver.OnResolve: Project1: Searching in:
> 'C:\myapp\sources\unittest\net6.0'.   AssemblyResolver.OnResolve:
> Project1:  Assembly path does not exist:
> 'C:\myapp\sources\unittest\net6.0\Project1.dll', returning.
> AssemblyResolver.OnResolve: Project1: Assembly path does not exist:
> 'C:\myapp\sources\unittest\net6.0\Project1.exe', returning.
> AssemblyResolver.OnResolve: Project1: Failed to load assembly.

It seems like it doesn't use the `runsettings` file where I specifically specified the `Directory path` under the `AssemblyResolution`

---

Edit #2:

I changed the `Directory path` in the `AssemblyResolution` in the `runsettings` file to use the absolute path to the bin folder, still it is not using that setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from the microsoft/testfx.

[ [MSTest][Discovery] Unable to load types from the test source ... Could not load file or assembly #1645](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/1645#issuecomment-1532574597)

> As you pointed out, you are using the AssemblyResolution configuration
> in the runsettings file. This property allows users to give different
> locations in which MSTest should try to be loading dlls from. This is
> used internally in a custom assembly resolver along with AppDomains.
>
> In netcore/net versions of .NET, some functionnalities of the
> AppDomain are no longer available which is preventing some of the
> behaviours of MSTest.
>
> To answer more specifically your questions. No, there will not be any
> "fix" for supporting the AssemblyResolution property in netcore/net
> versions of MSTest. But we will update the documentation to specify
> this is not supported AND we will emit a warning if we detect this
> property in some netcore run.
>
> As for workarounds, I would suggest "fixing" the project setup so that
> the dlls are found in the location of the test dll. As explained in
> some previous comment, you could remove the , you could add a
> task to copy the dlls in the custom location or edit the "production"
> projects to emit in the custom location

Answer (score -1):

You can try by using absolute path just for testing. I guess this is because of path only I too have encountered similar issue and was able to debug using absolute path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean putting the absolute path in the `.runsettings`? I've tried using `C:\myapp\sources` and `C:\myapp\sources\bin` and still no luck.
Edit: The test will eventually be running in a server, so I guess using absolute path is not a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SE! @RohitSingh Please improve your answer with a sample reproducible solution to the question.